# Cucumber/Selenium Maven Project - Running into step undefined issue even though I have steps defined in .java class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber

I have a very simple maven project setup and im using selenium webdriver and cucumber to run some basic tests. I have my step definitions .java file in a package under java > test and my .feature file in a resources folder which I have set as the test resources root.

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0lkA.png)

Here's the link to my repository in case that helps: https://github.com/mahmood-alsaftawi/AmazonSelenium

The things ive tried so far so updating intelliJ, ensuring the run config glue field was set to the step definitions .java file. Ive tried some other recommendations but I've had no luck.

Comment: Make sure your run configuration [looks like this](https://i.imgur.com/2oey7ty.png).

Comment: Also, copy this projects code. Your `pom.xml` is going to cause you grief in the long run. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried that exact config and still had the same issue

Comment: This config works for me in a project you shared. Using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was that the feature file couldn't find the location of your steps. I created a RunnerClass for you, and it worked out on my PC

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources",
        glue = "com.test.definitions"
)
public class CucumberRunner {

}
```

I'll add a Pull Request on your github project.

Comment: I got it to work without a runnerclass. But I also added it in to make things easier down the line, Thanks!